# SQL lateral view

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, hive

How can I use **lateral view** in SQL to extract values from JSON strings?

Example data in table "people":

```
name   information
-----  -----------------------
Jen    {"age": 15, "gender":2}
John   {"age": 22, "gender":1}
Jack   {"age": 25, "gender":1}
Pat    {"age": 55, "gender":3}
```

Comment: My advice is to write a script to iterate each row and store it into a properly normalized table rather than storing JSON.

Comment: The table with JSON is over a terrabyte, so storing it in a form with each column won't be usable.

Comment: But on a table that size, the string manipulations needed to parse the JSON will be quite unusable too (more so)

Comment: This is where SQL schemas win, that data is highly regular, very indexable, etc. You will do much better, IMO, to model that into your schema. Also, you will take up less space (think about this: how many times are the bytes "gender" in that table's data?)

Comment: can you show us table schema?

Comment: Is it correct to tag this question with [tag:mysql]? There is no lateral view feature in MySQL. IMO, you're asking about Hive, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name , info\
FROM people\
LATERAL VIEW explode(information) exploded_information_view AS info
```

should look something like this:

```
name / info

Jen    /   "age": 15 \
Jen     /  "gender":2
```